# Views not laying out as expected with AutoLayout while embedding a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, autolayout

What I'm going for seems simple enough, but I can't get things to lay out how I'm expecting. I'm using AutoLayout to avoid hardcoding frames when taking into account different screen sizes. AutoLayout is turned on for all .xibs, but I have not created any explicit constraints within Interface Builder.

ViewControllerA is embedding ViewControllerB and adding VCB's view to it's view hierarchy.
VCA has a TableView, and VCB has a UserView (just a normal view with subviews).

I want the TableView to sit on top of the UserView. The UserView has a fixed height and it's bottom will always stay fixed to the bottom of the screen. The TableView will fill the rest of the screen.

Here's what I have in code. This sticks the UserView to the bottom successfully:

```
userViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
NSDictionary *constrainedViews = @{ @"userView" : userViewController.view, @"menu" : self.menuTable };
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[userView]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:constrainedViews]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[userView(174)]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:constrainedViews]];
```

1) If I don't call `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` before adding the constraint, I get "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." in my console complaining about conflicting NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints. Why? I have AutoLayout turned on. I thought this error would only arise while combining AutoLayout and non-AutoLayout views. Is it because I have no explicit constraints set up in IB?

So I have the UserView aligned to the bottom as desired, and now I want to work on making the TableView stack on top and fill the remaining screen.If I replace the last constraint above (the Vertical constraint) with this:

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[menu][userView(174)]|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:constrainedViews]];
```

I get a bunch of errors in my console again.

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd39c880 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(0)-[UITableView:0xe914e00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xd39ea60 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd39c590 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UITableView:0xe914e00(362)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd3a4f60 V:[UITableView:0xe914e00]-(0)-[UIView:0xd39ff60]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xd3a4350 V:[UIView:0xd39ff60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xd39ea60 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xd3af6d0 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0xd39ff60.midY == UIView:0xd39ea60.midY>"
)
```

I've been stuck for hours and don't have a clue how to proceed. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Why is IB auto generating a fixed frame, and one that I can't override with my new constraint?

Comment: "I have not created any explicit constraints within Interface Builder" -- the fact that you didn't create them doesn't mean they weren't created for you by Xcode. You probably either need to modify the ones created for you in IB, or delete them and add your own.

Comment: When I look at ViewControllerA.xib, the only thing inside my view is a UITableViewController. It doesn't look like there are any constraints applied. I also logged out `[self.tableView constraints]` and it was an empty array.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Did you turn off auto layout?

Comment: Xcode 5-DP3. I only know how to turn auto layout off in a .xib, and it's on in all my .xibs.

Comment: I'm not asking about anything specific to content under the NDA. Auto layout predates Xcode 5, and that's what my question focuses on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34203/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-djibouti33)

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the broken constraints are on your superview, or the view containing the UITableView, rather than on the UITableView itself. If you plan on setting up those constraints in code, you should remove all of those automatic constraints first:

```
[self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That was simple versus all the other examples I've seen where people add constraints in Interface Builder and then check the "remove at build time" placeholder check box.

Comment: This works fine if *all* of your constraints are managed in code and you can just remove everything from your view. But if you have any interface builder constraints that you want to keep you'll have to go the route of adding constraints and marking them as placeholders. I swear, Apple dropped the ball on this design. What an ugly mess.

Comment: @devios , But if you mark them as placeholder they wont effect anytime when they are running. so why not removing them by code?

Comment: @roimulia I meant if there are constraints you want to keep, it's going to be harder.

Comment: @devios it his , I have this strange IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker crashes and more of this category. So i removed all constraints from the VC and still crushing. Any idea?

Comment: @roimulia You can remove those constraints. I'm not saying don't. I've had to do that myself before. But what are the actual errors? All I see are the constraints logged.

Comment: @devios a bunch of this ,  Again no constraint applies to the VC , it crashes after the view appeared(visually) and right after that crush with this log

Comment: @devios 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<NSISEngine: 0x155ca730>{ Rows:
 0x155a9450.posErrorMarker{id: 715} == 0 + 1*0x155a9450.negError{id: 716} + 1*_UILayoutGuide:0x155aa870.Width{id: 717}
 0x155aaa80.posErrorMarker{id: 718} == 0 + 1*0x155aaa80.negError{id: 719} + 1*_UILayoutGuide:0x155aa9e0.Width{id: 720}
<250:1>*0x155aa0f0:IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame.marker{id: 657} + <999:2>*0x155aaa80.negError{id: 719} + <750:-7.45058e-08>*0x156be120.negError{id: 111} + <750:1,

Comment: @roimulia You should open a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89983/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-devios).